# What to expect after 0 training with random initialization of weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training my network on MNIST. It is learning really well after some epochs. i am using initialization like in Tensorflow Tuto :

```
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
```

And, when I dont train it, I end up with always the same prediction (using softmax) like :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I was obviously not expecting it to classify well at all.

But I was expecting to have random prediction and not always same prediction.

Is this behaviour expected ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, could you paste some pieces of code which reproduce the error ?

Comment: No pb :) I don't know if this is an error. If I initialize randomly my weights shouldn't I end up with scores like [[ 0.14, 0.08, 0.03, 0.12, 0.15, 0.9, ...]] (what i would call random scores ?
I might not be an error, but if it's not I would like to understand why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have use a tensorflow graph that has been initialized with random weights that has not been trained, it is very much possible for the results to be all one class.

Let's explore this with XOR : 2 inputs, 3 hidden units, 1 output like so

```
W1_shape = [2,3] # in the range [-.1,.1]
b1_shape = [3]   # initialized to .1

W2_shape = [3,1] # in the range [-.1,.1]
b2_shape = [1]   # initialized to .1
```

Example values are

```
W1 [[-0.06278145 -0.01198458  0.12907881]
 [ 0.04213665  0.03700039 -0.05857842]]

b1 0.1

W2 [[ 0.14718919]
 [ 0.08633115]
 [ 0.10883235]]

b2 0.1
```

Which results in the XOR always reporting *slightly* TRUE.

After running the initialization 10 times the result is always the same, *slightly* TRUE for all cases of XOR.

If however, I change **b1** and **b2** to be 0.001, then the output is either all *slightly* TRUE or *slightly* FALSE, but not some mixed for a particular initialization.  Looking at the weights it becomes obvious that a few weights overpower the whole graph.  These weights are brought into line quickly with just a few training iterations.

Comment: Ok that what I was thinking as well and you gave me a concrete and more simple example, thank you for that ! :) And in fact when I'm training it quickly gives me better results (I guess they are, like you said, "brought into line", thank you Adam optimizer :) )